# How is it possible that I get different results depending on if I run the code statement by statement or as a block?

Tags: python, quotes, smtplib

I have a code for sending an email if a criteria is matched:

```py
import datetime
import smtplib

today = datetime.date.today()
email_date = today
items = [1, 2]
gmail_email = "put_your_email_here"
password = "put your password here"

if email_date == today:
    # send email
    sent_from = gmail_email
    sent_to = ['email_1', 'email_2']
    sent_subject = 'Subject of the email'
    sent_body = ("""Hello,

    This is part of a reproducible code

    Kind regards""")

    email_text = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ', '.join(sent_to), sent_subject, sent_body)

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, sent_to, email_text)
    server.close()
```

However, if I run the entire code, the email that is sent has empty subject and empty body and everything is placed in the "from" of the email.

If I run statement by statement (starting after the conditional) I get the email correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you have something that is asynchronous and you close too soon?

Comment: Are you using this code in a function with global variables?

Comment: Each line in `email_text` has to be terminated with a CFLF pair, not just a LF. I'm not sure what you mean by "statement by statement", but that could be affecting the definition of `email_text`.

Comment: What happens if you use something like `email_text = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n%s\r\n" % (sent_from, ', '.join(sent_to), sent_subject, sent_body)` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably related to the way you are assigning the text block to the  email_text variable. The text is indented, while the email should have the header fields at the beginning of the line. Try changing it to:

```
        email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" %(sent_from, ', '.join(sent_to), sent_subject, sent_body)
```